# How to fix icon column alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm quite new in the field and I want to create tabs and I found the following process tab function.
https://codepen.io/rt99/pen/BaBWwRG

I want to add new processes/icons with it, but it shows on the next line no t on the current one. I want all of them to be in the same line.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
```

I got quite confused while going through the resource about what should I change.

Comment: Grammar improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix is using`float:left` and make width equal `width: calc(100%/6);`. Modify as below

```
.process-model li {
  width: calc(100%/6);
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

```js
// script for tab steps
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {

  var href = $(e.target).attr('href');
  var $curr = $(".process-model  a[href='" + href + "']").parent();

  $('.process-model li').removeClass();

  $curr.addClass("active");
  $curr.prevAll().addClass("visited");
});
// end  script for tab steps
```

```css
.design-process-section .text-align-center {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.design-process-content {
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  position: relative;
  padding: 16px 34% 30px 30px;
}

.design-process-content img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.design-process-content h3 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.design-process-content p {
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.process-model {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto 26px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 0;
}

.process-model li::after {
  background: #e5e5e5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: 33px;
  width: 85%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.process-model li.visited::after {
  background: #57b87b;
}

.process-model li:last-child::after {
  width: 0;
}

.process-model li {
  width: calc(100%/6);
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-tabs.process-model>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs.process-model>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs.process-model>li.active>a:focus,
.process-model li a:hover,
.process-model li a:focus {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.process-model li a {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  color: #606060;
}

.process-model li.active,
.process-model li.visited {
  color: #57b87b;
}

.process-model li.active a,
.process-model li.active a:hover,
.process-model li.active a:focus,
.process-model li.visited a,
.process-model li.visited a:hover,
.process-model li.visited a:focus {
  color: #57b87b;
}

.process-model li.active p,
.process-model li.visited p {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.process-model li i {
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f5f6f7;
  border: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.process-model li.active i,
.process-model li.visited i {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #57b87b;
}

.process-model li p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.process-model.contact-us-tab li.visited a,
.process-model.contact-us-tab li.visited p {
  color: #606060!important;
  font-weight: normal
}

.process-model.contact-us-tab li::after {
  display: none;
}

.process-model.contact-us-tab li.visited i {
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  .more-icon-preocess.process-model li span {
    font-size: 23px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 46px;
    width: 50px;
  }
  .more-icon-preocess.process-model li::after {
    top: 24px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .process-model.more-icon-preocess li {
    width: 16%;
  }
  .more-icon-preocess.process-model li span {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 32px;
    width: 35px;
  }
  .more-icon-preocess.process-model li p {
    font-size: 8px;
  }
  .more-icon-preocess.process-model li::after {
    top: 18px;
  }
  .process-model.more-icon-preocess {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="design-process-section" id="process-tab">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <!-- design process steps-->
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs process-model more-icon-preocess" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#discover" aria-controls="discover" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-coffee" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>Discover</p>
            </a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#strategy" aria-controls="strategy" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-send-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>Strategy</p>
            </a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#optimization" aria-controls="optimization" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-qrcode" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>Optimization</p>
            </a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#content" aria-controls="content" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>Content</p>
            </a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#reporting" aria-controls="reporting" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>Reporting</p>
            </a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#testing" aria-controls="testing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <p>Testing</p>
            </a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- end design process steps-->
        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="discover">
            <div class="design-process-content">
              <h3 class="semi-bold">Discovery</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincid unt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="strategy">
            <div class="design-process-content">
              <h3 class="semi-bold">Strategy</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincid unt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="optimization">
            <div class="design-process-content">
              <h3 class="semi-bold">Optimization</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincid unt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="content">
            <div class="design-process-content">
              <h3 class="semi-bold">Content</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincid unt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="reporting">
            <div class="design-process-content">
              <h3>Reporting</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincid unt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following code in the CSS.

```
.process-model li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16%; <-- changed from 18% to 16%
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each li has 18% width. so 6 are more than a 100%.
change the width to 16%.

```
.process-model li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16%;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/urich/pen/WNepZzq

Answer (score 0):

`.process-model li` has `width:18%;` 100(percent of max-width)/6(li) would give you 16% and some decimal extra, therefore you should change it to 16% or less. But really, it should take you a lot less code to achieve that result.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this css

```
.process-model{
  display: flex;
}
```

to get icon in one line. if you want to know more about flex go to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to just change one css, in .process-model li 
replace width: calc(100%/6) by  width: calc(100%/7) so 7th iteam will adjust automatically.

```css
.process-model li {
    width: calc(100%/7);
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Please refer below example for more detail,
https://jsfiddle.net/jignashagpatel/tgy13o94/1/